# All in one 'alternatives Q' are acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Why was the following Q/A closed: [What default Windows Software Alternatives does Ubuntu have!](https://askubuntu.com/q/389228/36315)?

I get that it is a "big list" and that they are generally not allowed. But, there are way to many "alternatives" Q's on here to not have it!

Some big list generators:

- [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)
- [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)
- [What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)
- [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) [on hold]
- [What native games are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available)

Comment: Please, point to those Questions for re-evaluation. If those questions generates or gives the impression that big lists are allowed then I'm hands down to close them too.

Comment: @Braiam, I edited my Q!

Comment: It's something good for your question to be closed. This would get all the focus on your answer. Although I _think_ it's a bit better for it to be "locked" rather than closed just to indicate that it's useful but it shouldn't be edited! Actually it's the best question I've ever seen till now.

Answer (score 7):

It's been closed as "too broad"... Because it is. It's like a normal software recommendation on steroids.

You might as well ask "What is all the software in the Ubuntu repositories and what does it do?"

---

The exception to something like this is if somebody:

- Set up a wiki page on [wiki.ubuntu.com](http://wiki.ubuntu.com) that documented the default applications and how they relate to Windows counterparts (or vice versa)
- Used an answer here to push somebody to that page.
- Rephrased the question to be more about how to find alternatives rather than asking for a list.

Comment: First part, True, but, I think this could greatly benefit new users, as a one page find all. Second, are linked answer not allowed also?

Comment: @blade19899 If you mean answers that are only a link, yeah, those get deleted or moved into comments quite frequently. Answers are supposed to *answer* the question, not provide pointers or comments that help. That's what the comment section is for ;)

Comment: @Seth It's not that black and white. Usually *just* posting a link is considered bad form but for any given problem an answer in the form of a link is probably better than no answers at all... But even if the main part of the answer is "Look over there", you can still add context to your answer that explains why you're sending the person there.

Comment: @Oli Adding context would indeed make it an answer. However according to [help/how-to-answer] answers are supposed to be self supporting, include context for links and just generally *answer the question*. After all, the comment section is there for a reason. I guess the definition of "link only answer" could be a bit of a problem here. If it has any context at all it should be fine IMO.

Comment: Hmm. Donno why that magic link didn't work. Here's the full link: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You sure you want to lock this? http://askubuntu.com/q/389228/169736