# Do we need big lists?

Tags: discussion, scope

So, the Don't ask section specifically says:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. **If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.**

furthermore:

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite **__**?”
>
> are more than just mindless social fun.

So, I've always seen in SO where questions that tend to generate list ("Good book about C?", I swear there's one but about Ubuntu here) are promptly closed **and** downvoted, to set an example that those questions are not welcomed.

Well, when we were almost just a year old (more or less) there was an spawn of "recommendation" and "lists" questions here on Ask Ubuntu. Stack Overflow crossed that path too and they decided that Stack Exchange is not the place to do "lists" nor ask for "recommendations" but about Questions that have at least **one** valid and definitive answer. Is Ask Ubuntu different?

Relevant:

- [What's the final word on "What X are available" and "List of X" type questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1511/169736) (this says that only "pro-tips" like easter eggs that are not endless)
- [All in one 'alternatives Q' are acceptable?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7946/169736)

Comment: Do we need them? maybe, do we want them? hell yes!

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Questions asking for big list answers shouldn't be allowed. Questions asking for a site/sites containing a big list for some specific topic should be allowed. The latter could be answered in a Q&A style, the former couldn't.